# Getting the specific value of the last 3 months of a record without duplicate

Tags: sql

*UPDATE

Im trying to get the **Amount Paid** for the 3 previous months of a record with the same classification regardless of component.

- I tried the new code and it gives me the output I want but, the value is still duplicating for each component.

This is the sample records in the database:

[image]

and this is the code that I've tried so far *new code:

```
    SELECT * 
    INTO #Q1
    FROM TenantRecord

    --GET Previous MONTH
    SELECT * 
    INTO #Q2
    FROM TenantRecord
    where Date between @PREVMonthStart and @PREVMonthEnd

    --GET Previous 2nd MONTH
    SELECT * 
    INTO #Q3
    FROM TenantRecord
    where Date between @PREV2ndMonthStart and @PREV2ndMonthEnd

    --GET Previous 3rd MONTH
    SELECT * 
    INTO #Q4
    FROM TenantRecord
    where Date between @PREV3rdMonthStart and @PREV3rdMonthEnd

    select a.Tenant, a.Classification, a.Date, a.Component, a.AmountP,
    (case when b.Classification != a.Classification then null else b.AmountP end) as Previous1, 
    (case when c.Classification != a.Classification then null else c.AmountP end) as Previous2,
    (case when d.Classification != a.Classification then null else d.AmountP end) as Previous3
    from #Q1 a 
    LEFT JOIN #Q2 b on a.Tenant = b.Tenant
    LEFT JOIN #Q3 c on a.Tenant = c. Tenant
    LEFT JOIN #Q4 d on a.Tenant = d.Tenant

    where date between @CurrentMonthStart and @CurrentMonthEnd
```

This is the output of the code:

[image]

But the output that I want is this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

Please review this possible solution:

```
Declare @currentDate date = '2016-07-30';
With cte As (
    Select Tenant, Classification, Component, Month([Date]) As [Month], Amount
      From #TenantRecord
      Where Year([Date]) >= Year(DateAdd(Month, -4, @currentDate))
        And Month([Date]) >= Month(DateAdd(Month, -4, @currentDate)))
Select Tenant, Classification, Component, July = [7], June = [6], May = [5], April = [4]
  From cte
  Pivot (Sum(Amount) For [Month] In ([4], [5], [6], [7])) As pvt;
```

I'm a little hazy on whether the language elements that I've used comply with the ISO standard SQL, and you haven't specified an RDBMS. This should work on Microsoft [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server).

**Edit:**

```
Declare @currentDate date = '2016-07-30';
With cte As (
    Select Tenant, Classification, AmountPaid, 
        Month(@currentDate) - Month([Date]) As [MonthsAgo]
      From #TenantRecord
      Where Year([Date]) >= Year(DateAdd(Month, -4, @currentDate))
        And Month([Date]) >= Month(DateAdd(Month, -4, @currentDate))),
PivotByTenantClassification As (
    Select Tenant, Classification, [0], [1], [2], [3]
      From cte
      Pivot (Sum(AmountPaid) For [MonthsAgo] In ([0], [1], [2], [3])) As pvt)
Select t.Tenant, t.Classification, t.Date, t.Component, [0], [1], [2], [3]
  From #TenantRecord As t
  Join PivotByTenantClassification As pvt 
    On t.Tenant  = pvt.Tenant
    And t.Classification = pvt.Classification
  Where Year([Date]) = Year(@currentDate)
    And Month([Date]) = Month(@currentDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what I want is to get all the value and not the total of the last 3 months just like in the 3rd pic.

Comment: @KevinNEWBIE somewhat more complicated to do that, and slightly strange that there will be a line for each amount paid by classification in the current month. See edited example.